# Plotting a two-way ANOVA with "short" dependent variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, points, anova

my problem is simple and complicated at the same time
I would like to make graph of boxplots **exactly** like the first one of this post  http://www.r-bloggers.com/let%E2%80%99s-all-go-down-to-the-barplot/
The problem is that the variable of my y-axis has only 4-points. The boxes cover most of the area and it is not visible whether there is higher frequency of occurrence of the 1st point or of the 4th point, etc.
I would like not to transform the y-axis variable since as it is it makes sense. I thought of a density plot, does anybody have an idea on how to plot something like this?
Thank you in advance

--- EDIT ---

I apologise for not being specific enough, my data are the variables of a factorial two-way ANOVA where the outcome variable has too few points to be successfully plotted by a boxplot or something like this http://rgm3.lab.nig.ac.jp/RGM-files//work/granova/granova.1w/granova.1w_001_large.png

In my model  "4-point scale" = factor1 + factor2 + factor1*factor2 + e
I would like initially to plot a factor1 x factor2 plot where the points will show the count of observations of the 4-point scale. In order to show you what I mean I produced a plot, the factor1 clusters together the levels of factor2 and on the y axis we can see the *levels* of the 4-point-scale/continuous variable.
Following your advice I tried to replicate with the esoph data and constructed a vioplot

```
library(ggplot2)
str(esoph)
p11 <- ggplot(esoph, aes(factor(tobgp), ncontrols))
p11 + geom_violin(aes(fill=factor(agegp)))
```

In my data due to the small number of points on the y-axis the vioplots almost look alike (even if the model is significant, including the interaction), unlike the plot that is produced by the code above (I need to subset the ncontrols to a smaller number of points but I do not know how...).
Is it possible to produce circles or bubbles, the size of which will indicate the number of obsrvations?
Does another solution come to mind?

Comment: this is interesting, but not a programming question.  I would suggest migration to http://stats.stackexchange.com . I would say your data are not appropriate for a boxplot: I would probably use a beanplot or beeswarm plot (search for them on Google or SO), depending on your data set size. (OK, it *could* be construed as a programming problem, if you say "... and please show me the code to do it ...)

Comment: It would really help if you created a little reproducible example, like an example of the data set that you have. You could also copy the image from the website you posted (in addition to the link) so that if the link ever breaks we still have the picture.

Comment: So is the y axis categorical? Or you have only four observations per group? Either way, it sounds like a boxplot is not the way you want to go - displaying the points would likely make more sense. Without an example of your data it's hard to know for sure

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of boxplots is to summarize data so that it's easier to interpret.  You have 4 data points per condition.  Just plot all of the points.  In fact, even if you ignore this suggestion and eventually make boxplots, overlay all of the points on the boxplot in grey with transparency.

If you want to expand the y-axis you can pass a ylim argument to the boxplot call.